# Using `awk` to print number of lines in file in the BEGIN section

Tags: text, awk, text-processing

I am trying to write an awk script and before anything is done tell the user how many lines are in the file. I know how to do this in the END section but unable to do so in the BEGIN section.  I have searched SE and Google but have only found a half dozen ways to do this in the END section or as part of a bash script, not how to do it before any processing has taken place at all. I was hoping for something like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{
        print "There are a total of " **TOTAL LINES** " lines in this file.\n"
     }
{

        if($0==4587){print "Found record on line number "NR; exit 0;}
}
```

But have been unable to determine how to do this, if it is even possible. Thanks.

Comment: What would your desired output be if the input file is empty? Do you need to be able to process multiple files simultaneously?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read the file twice:

```
awk 'NR!=1 && FNR==1 {print NR-1} <some more code here>' file{,}
```

In your example:

```
awk 'NR!=1 && FNR==1 {print "There are a total of "NR-1" lines in this file.\n"} $0==4587 {print "Found record on line number "NR; exit 0;}' file{,}
```

You can use `file file` instead of  `file{,}` (it just makes it show up twice)
`NR!=1 && FNR==1` this will be true only at first line of second file.

---

To use an `awk` script containing:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
NR!=1 && FNR==1 {
    print "There are a total of "NR-1" lines in this file.\n"
    } 
$0==4587 {
    print "Found record on line number "NR; exit 0
    }
```

call:

```
awk -f myscript file{,}
```

Comment: How would I use this from inside of my awk script.  Would I just create another BEGIN section below the end of my TOTAL LINE count awk script in the same file?

Comment: Ok thanks for the edit, that clarified it for me. Thanks, guess I was just hoping for some magical built in variable or something. My files are too big, the user will just have to deal.  But this answers my question perfect.  Thanks! +1 accepted

Comment: @Dylan You could use `wc -l file `within the `awk` script, but this would add an extra tool, and also need to read the two time, one for  `wc` and one for `awk`

Comment: Yeah I thought of even passing the wc output to awk as a parameter but it just isnt worth the time itll take.  I just figured if awk counted all of the lines in the file anyways I might as well use it. But seeing this it just seems to be a waste of time for just a convenience.

Comment: @Dylan Shortened it some, no need for the `a` variable, when we already have the `NR` counter :)

Comment: lol ok awesome! Thank you for that, I was sitting here racking my brain trying to figure out why you did it that way.  Awesome, Also appreciate you making it so that it will handle multiple input files instead of just one.  Saved me a step!

Comment: @Dylan you misunderstand - this will not handle multiple input files, it will only handle one. It just has to read that one file twice to count the number of lines before going anything else. It will fail for empty files - is that OK?

Comment: Works nicely with a _single, nonempty_ input file (passed twice), as noted. To prevent processing the actual commands (`<some more code here>`) _twice_ too, the program should start with `NR==FNR {next} `. That then allows simplifying `NR!=1 && FNR==1` to `FNR==1`.

Comment: @mklement0 Here you are wrong.  This  `NR==FNR {next}` will not be run just one.  It will be run as long as there are more line to pas in first pass.  So if there are 100 lines, it will run the `<some more code here>` 100 times.  This  `NR!=1 && FNR==1` is only run once it the whole process (as long as there are only two files).

Comment: @Jotne: The behavior you describe is what _your_ code currently does: it ultimately runs `<some more code here>` _twice_ fore each input line, which is not the intent (the intent is to _only count_ first, then to _only process_). Not sure where our disconnect is, but let me write out what I think the entire command should be (uses a simple `print` as the _processing_ command): `awk 'NR==FNR {next} FNR==1 {print NR-1} { print }' file{,}`

Comment: @mklement0 No, you are wrong.  `FNR` is `1` for first line of every file. `NR` increment all the time, so its just `1` for the first line of first file.  So this  `NR!=1 && FNR==1` will only be true after first file is done, and at the first line of the second file (or first line of third file, fourth file etc).  Tested and confirmed.

Comment: @Jotne the problem isn't with your first block it's with your second one. Since you don't have an `NR==FNR{next}` block, `$0==4587 {...}` would be executed twice if it wasn't for the `exit` in it. If the target value `4587` is present in the file your script will print the line it occurs on and exit without ever printing the number of lines in the file.

Comment: @EdMorton's point is valid. My solution solves this problem _generically_: The purpose of `NR==FNR` is to _ignore the entire 1st pass_ in terms of _processing_ (as opposed to _counting_), so that, on then encountering the 1st line in the 2nd pass (`FNR==1`), you can print the count (`NR-1`), and perform the _subsequent processing only once_. Note how the OP wants to print the count _before_ processing the lines.

Comment: @mklement0 it take some time to sink in.  Can be solved with `$0==4587 && FNR!=NR`

Comment: Adding a `NR==FNR{next}` block at the start is simpler, clearer and briefer.

Answer (score 2):

To do this robustly and for multiple files you need something like:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGINFILE {
    numLines = 0
    while ( (getline line < FILENAME) > 0 ) {
        numLines++
    }
    print "----\nThere are a total of", numLines, "lines in", FILENAME
}
$0==4587 { print "Found record on line number", FNR, "of", FILENAME; nextfile }
$
$ cat file1
a
4587
c
$
$ cat file2
$
$ cat file3
d
e
f
4587
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2 file3
----
There are a total of 3 lines in file1
Found record on line number 2 of file1
----
There are a total of 0 lines in file2
----
There are a total of 4 lines in file3
Found record on line number 4 of file3
```

The above uses GNU awk for BEGINFILE. Any other solution is difficult to implement such that it will handle empty files (you need an array to track files being parsed and print info the the `FNR==1` and `END` sections after the empty file has been skipped).

Using getline has caveats and should not be used lightly, see http://awk.info/?tip/getline, but this is one of the appropriate and robust uses of it. You can also test for non-readable files in BEGINFILE  by testing ERRNO and skipping the file (see the gawk manual) - that situation will cause other scripts to abort.

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN {
s="cat your_file.txt|wc -l"; 
s | getline file_size;
close(s);
print file_size 
}
```

This will put the size of the file named `your_file.txt` into the awk variable file_size and print it out.

If your file name is dynamic you can pass the filename on the commandline and change the script to use the variable.

E.g. `my.awk`

```
BEGIN {
s="cat "VAR"|wc -l"; 
s | getline file_size;
close(s);
print file_size 
}
```

Then you can call it like this: 
`awk -v VAR="your_file.txt" -f my.awk`

Comment: 1) UUOC: use `wc -l < file` instead of `cat file | wc -l`. 2) unquoted variable wil cause failures when spaces in file name: use `cat \""VAR\""..."` not `cat "VAR"..."`. 2) Unchecked getline result will print previous success value on failure: use `if ( (s | getline file_size) < 1) ? file_size=-1 )` not `s | getline file_size`. 4) Lose the useless semi-colons, this is awk not C. 5) It cannot test for the target value `4587`. 6) Passing a file name as a variable to make awk behave like shell is useless.

Comment: @Ed The OP asked how to print the number of lines in the BEGIN block, not how to code safe. For the variable not quoted you could push the requirement out to the user `awk -v VAR ="\"your spaced out filename\"" -f my.awk`

Answer (score 0):

If you use ***GNU* `awk`** and need a **robust, generic solution that accommodates *multiple, possibly empty* input files**, **use [Ed Morton's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) solution**.

This answer uses **portable (POSIX-compliant) code**. Within the constraints noted, it is robust, but Ed's *GNU* `awk` solution is both simpler and more robust.
Tip of the hat to Ed Morton for his help.

With a ***single* input file**, it is **simpler to handle line counting with a *shell* command in the `BEGIN` block**, which has the following advantages:

- on invocation, the filename doesn't have to be specified *twice*, unlike in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29314659/45375)

  - Also note that the accepted answer doesn't work as intended (as of this writing); the correct form is (see the comments on the answer for an explanation):

    - `awk 'NR==FNR {next} FNR==1 {print NR-1} $0==4587 {print "Found record on line number "NR; exit 0}' file{,}`
- the solution also works with an *empty* input file.

In terms of performance, this approach is either only slightly slower than reading the file twice in `awk`, or even a little faster, depending on the `awk` implementation used:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
     # Execute a shell command to count the lines and read
     # result into an awk variable via <cmd> | getline <varname>.
     # If the file cannot be read, abort. (The shell has already printed an error msg.)
    cmd="wc -l < \"" ARGV[1] "\""; if ((cmd | getline count) < 1) exit 1; close(cmd)
    printf "There are a total of %s lines in this file.\n\n", count
  }
  $0==4587 { print "Found record on line number " NR; exit 0 }
' file
```

**Assumptions**:

- The filename is passed as the 1st operand (non-option argument) on the command line, accessed as `ARGV[1]`.
- The filename doesn't contain embedded `"` chars.

---

The following solutions deal with ***multiple* files** and make analogous **assumptions**:

- All operands passed are filenames. That is, all arguments after the program must be *filenames*, and not variable assignments such as `var=value`.
- No filename contains embedded `"` chars.
- No processing is to take place if *any* of the input files do not exist or cannot be read.

It's not hard to generalize this to **handling *multiple* files**, but the following solution ***doesn't* print the line count for *empty* files**:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
     # Loop over all input files and store their line counts in an array.
    for (i=1; i<ARGC; ++i) {
      cmd="wc -l < \"" ARGV[i] "\""; if ((cmd | getline count) < 1) exit 1; close(cmd)
      counts[ARGV[i]] = count
    }
  }
   # At the beginning of every (non-empty) file, print the line count.
  FNR==1 { printf "There are a total of %s lines in file %s.\n\n", counts[FILENAME], FILENAME }
  # $0==4587 { print "%s: Found record on line number %d\n", FILENAME, NR; exit 0 }
' file1 file2 # ...
```

---

Things get a little **trickier** if you want the **line count to be printed for *empty* files also**:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
     # Loop over all input files and store their line counts in an array.
    for (i=1; i<ARGC; ++i) {
      cmd="wc -l < \"" ARGV[i] "\""; if ((cmd | getline count) < 1) exit 1; close(cmd)
      counts[ARGV[i]] = count
    }
    fileCount = ARGC - 1
    fmtStringCount = "There are a total of %s lines in file %s.\n\n"
  }
   # At the beginning of every (non-empty) file, print the line count.
  FNR==1 {
   ++fileIndex
    # If there were intervening empty files, print their counts too.
   while (ARGV[fileIndex] != FILENAME) {
       printf fmtStringCount, 0, ARGV[fileIndex++]
   }
   printf fmtStringCount, counts[FILENAME], FILENAME
  }
   # Process input lines
  $0==4587 { print "%s: Found record on line number %d\n", FILENAME, NR; exit 0 }
   # If there are any remaining empty files a the end, print their counts too.
  END {
    while (fileIndex < fileCount) { printf fmtStringCount, 0, ARGV[++fileIndex] }
  }
' file1 file2 # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of lines by `wc` and `cut`, and set to `awk` variable with `-v` option, then you can use the variable in `awk` script.

```bash
cat awk.txt \
    | awk -v FNC=`wc -l awk.txt | cut -wf 2` \
          'BEGIN { print "FNC: " FNC } { print $0 }'
```